# Querying z-values in cranvas qtime

Tags: r

I need to interactively explore profiles of of a y variable (reflectance) against an x variable (wavelength) in plots that are very similar to time plots. My problem is that
besides checking the exact x,y values, I also would need to get the channel (that is,
a third variable). I do not see a way of doing this with qplot(), is it?
Actually, if using the "?" key with qscatter() you get x,y and ID, so we are not that far...

Thanks,

Agus

Answer (score 0):

The current solution is through linking plots, such as:
qtime(time=TimeIndx, y=ts, data=qnasa)
qscatter(ts, o3_tovs, data=qnasa)

Then brush some points, you will see highlights on both plots.

According  to Xiaoyue, referring to something like 
qtime(time=TimeIndx, y=ts, z=o3_tovs, data=qnasa)
(indicating that the plot is made by y vs x but the "tips note" would show the values for x,y,z)

"Currently we don't allow the user to add something to the label, but it is possible to change the setting later."

See
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cranvas/D4-uh98p95A
for more information